# How to save a Windows Snipping Tool screenshot if the pop up or the message center does not let you left click to open the screenshot in a new window?

Tags: windows, screenshot, snipping-tool

This happened only a few times over some years:

After taking a screenshot with the Windows Snipping Tool App:

[image]

Sometimes, you then cannot left click the pop up or message to get to the new window of that screenshot. But only in the new window, you can save it somewhere, copy it to the clipboard, or work on it:

[image]

How to save a Windows Snipping Tool screenshot if the pop up or the message center does not let you left click to open the screenshot in a new window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of left clicking the pop up or the message, right click the pop up. By this, the new window opened up even if a left click did not change anything on the screen.

*I did not test this right click on the message in the message center. Perhaps, that would have worked anyway already with the left click, but I remember that after a click on the pop up, you lose the screenshot message of the message center. I did not check this any further, but I remember from other lost screenshots that the message in the message center did not let you left click for the needed new window either.*

I found this workaround only now, after losing perhaps just a dozen screenshots over the years, and I wonder whether I really did not check this workaround. If I tried it, I must have forgotten about this "trick", or it just does not always work.

In short, I cannot say whether this always works.

Answer (score 0):

Left click is used for accessing the toolbar and File, Edit, Tools, and Help menus. Instead of left clicking, use right click on the mouse to see the context menu that contains Send To, Copy, Save As, Options, and Help.

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me as such, it seems. If I make a Snipping Tool screenshot, and it works as it should, and if I then right click on the pop up or on the message in the message center, the menu gives me two choices: whether I wanted to change to the message center settings, or whether I wanted to deactivate all messages for cutting and sketching. While in my workaround of right clicking the pop up, I did not get any meny, but I simply got into the edit window of the picture.